# Dereference a pointer inside a structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a structure:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int* pointer;
};

structure mystruct* struct_inst;
```

Now I want to change the value pointed to by `struct_inst->pointer`. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I didn't write it, but `pointer` already points to an area of memory allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: It's trivial, but "structure mystruct* struct_inst" should be "struct mystruct* struct_inst".

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As with any pointer. To change the *address* it points to:

`struct_inst->pointer = &var;`

To change the *value* at the address to which it points:

`*(struct_inst->pointer) = var;`

Comment: Perfect, the second one was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: thank you. god i love how you can always get a straight answer on here

Comment: I would definitely use the parentheses to be sure, but is it necessary

Comment: looks like not needed as structure member takes precedence http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @robisrob No, they are not necessary. But while writing the answer I had to pause for a moment to think about whether they were necessary, so I added them despite concluding that they are not… =)

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a pointer of type mystruct, I think perhaps you didn't want a pointer:

```
int x;
struct mystruct mystruct_inst;
mystruct_inst.pointer = &x;
*mystruct_inst.pointer = 33;
```

Of if you need a mystruct pointer on the heap instead:

```
int x;
struct mystruct *mystruct_inst = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
mystruct_inst->pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
*(mystruct_inst->pointer) = 33;  

/*Sometime later*/

free(mystruct_inst->pointer);
free(mystruct_inst);
```

Comment: I wanted a pointer. The value change takes place inside a function. Plus, I already assigned `pointer` to a malloc-ed area of memory.

Comment: I guess the answer's point was that your code example didn't show allocating any memory for the `struct mystruct`, just an uninitialised pointer to such a struct. But of course `pointer` inside the struct must also point somewhere. =)