# Printing a C Pointer as %i and %u

Tags: c, pointers, casting, hex

Context: Established programmer, revisiting C, not for any particular purpose other than better understanding what's really going on behind the scenes.

Consider this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581769/dereference-a-pointer-inside-a-structure-pointer

    int concreteInteger = 42;
    int* pointerInteger;
    pointerInteger = &concreteInteger;

    printf("concreteInteger as %%i = %i\n",concreteInteger);
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%p = %p\n" ,(void*)pointerInteger);        
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%u = %u\n" ,(unsigned)pointerInteger);                
    printf("*pointerInteger as %%i = %i\n",*pointerInteger);
    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this program on OS X 10.11, I get the following output.

```
$ cc main.c;./a.out 
concreteInteger as %i = 42
pointerInteger  as %p = 0x7fff5d614878
pointerInteger  as %u = 1566656632
*pointerInteger as %i = 42
Done
```

Where does `1566656632` come from?  If I [convert `1566656632` to hex](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=convert+1350785144+to+hex) I get `0x5D614878`, not `0x7fff5d614878`.

So where does `1566656632` come from?  What incorrect assumption am I making above?  Is casting a pointer as an unsigned number something that's undefined in C?  If so, for bonus points, if I wanted to represent the hex address of a pointer as a number in base 10, what's the most straight forward way to do that?

Comment: You get 0x50835878 because that is the lower 4 bytes of 0x7fff50835878

Comment: Thank you @ChrisTurner -- yours and chux's comments below made me realize how faceplamy assuming a pointer address would fit in an int was!

Comment: @AlanStorm, the addresses in your output and discussion after it do no match. Perhaps different runs. Please fix that first. Causes so much confusion.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya D'oh!  Sorry about that.  I think its fixed.  Copy/pasting from multiple runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion of a `int*` to `void*` does not lose needed information to reference the data as a conversion back to `int*` can reference `concreteInteger`.

Conversion of OP's `int*` to `unsigned` (32-bit) retained only 32-bits of the pointer's address.

Try `%x` and convert to `uintptr_t` first.
`uintptr_t` is in C99 and is an *optional* type, yet very commonly available.

```
 #include <stdint.h>
 ...
 printf("pointerInteger  as %%x = %x\n" ,(unsigned)(uintptr_t) pointerInteger);
```

I'd expect the following, the lower 32-bits of the pointer.  [@Chris Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549669/printing-a-c-pointer-as-i-and-u#comment76090242_44549669)

```
pointerInteger  as %x = 51af8878
```

Try `%llx` and convert to `uintptr_t` first to see more.

```
 printf("pointerInteger  as %%llx = %llx\n", 
    (unsigned long long)(uintptr_t) pointerInteger);
```

With macros in `<inttypes.h>`, a matching print specifier can be use to print `uintptr_t` types directly.

```
 printf("pointerInteger  %" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) pointerInteger);
```

---

> ... to represent the hex address of a pointer as a number in base 10, what's the most straight forward way to do that?

The address of a pointer is not "hex", it is what is is.  To *display* a pointer in decimal/hex/octal, convert to a wide enough integer and print using the matching print specifier.  To print most portably, convert to `void*` and use `"%p"`, which may print in hex.

---

Comment: "Conversion of a int* to void* does not lose needed information to reference the data." - That's not exactly correct. There might be less information in the `void *`. Only conversion to and back **to the same type** is guaranteeed to compare equal. That does not imply there is no information lost in the `void *` (at least the original type information is always lost)..And conversion of a pointr to an inteer is implementation defined. There is no guarantee it is truncated.

Comment: @chux Thank you for the attention and the help.  Re: the `uintptr_t` type -- is that something that's part of standard C systems?  In some library?  I ended up with a `use of undeclared identifier 'uintptr_t'` warning when I tried to use it.

Comment: @AlanStorm Look for `uintptr_t` in `<stdint.h>`.  C11 and maybe C99 includes it.  It is an _optional_ integer type, yet very likely defined.  It is part of the C standard.  If not found, cast to  `unsigned long long` and `"%llx"`

Comment: Thanks @chux, `stdint.h` did it (although so did `inttypes.h` so, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯) Also, for anyone else coming along, I'm going to tack on the formats I ended up using to @chux's answers for completeness.

Comment: @AlanStorm Better to post your own answer or append to your post than change this answer.  Suggest rolling back the edit.  BTW: `%lx\n" ,(uintptr_t)` is not necessarily matching.

Comment: @chux Sure thing.

Comment: Why not use the correct conversion type specifier for `uintptr_t` at least? Not that it really makes sense not to use `%p`.

Comment: @Olaf in _C11 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function_,  I did  not not see a specified matching print specifier for `uintptr_t` as so did not include [that idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549669/printing-a-c-pointer-as-i-and-u/44549984?noredirect=1#comment76092398_44549984) here.

Comment: @chux: There is also none for `uint32_t` in the function itself. You are aware about `inttypes.h`? (yes, `%zu` is superfluous actually, too). As with all your code above: the conversion of the pointer is implementation defined and printing the integers is even less defined.

Answer (score 0):

I marked the answer above as best because it got me where I needed to be, but the following program gave me what I wanted/needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//needed for the PRI*PTR Macros
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    //#include <inttypes.h>    
    int concreteInteger = 42;
    int* pointerInteger;
    pointerInteger = &concreteInteger;

    printf("concreteInteger as %%i = %i\n",concreteInteger);
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%p = %p\n" ,(void*)pointerInteger);        
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%u = %u\n" ,(unsigned)pointerInteger);                
    printf("*pointerInteger as %%i = %i\n",*pointerInteger);

    //as base 10 printf
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%lu = %lu\n" ,(uintptr_t)pointerInteger);                    
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%llu = %llu\n" ,(unsigned long long)(uintptr_t)pointerInteger);                    

    //as hex printf
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%lx = %lx\n" ,(uintptr_t)pointerInteger);           
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%llx = %llx\n" ,(unsigned long long)pointerInteger);           

    //using macros from inttypes.h
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%PRIxPTR = %" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) pointerInteger);         
    printf("pointerInteger  as %%PRIxPTR = %" PRIdPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) pointerInteger);         

    // 140,734,665,721,976

    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

A few key things to take away.

1. I needed to the `stdint.h` library to get the `(uintptr_t)` type.
2. The compiler warnings let me know that `%lu` and `%lx` were the format strings for displaying a `(uintptr_t)`
3. Per @chux above, casting the pointer as a `(unsigned long long)` required `%llu` and `%llx`
4. The converters over on [binaryhexconverter.com](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/) are super useful

Comment: `uintptr_t` might not be the same type as `unsigned long`, so `printf("pointerInteger  as %%lu = %lu\n" ,(uintptr_t)pointerInteger);` may need work on other platforms.

Comment: You need `"%" PRIuPTR` to print a `uintptr_t` portably, not `"%lu"`.  You need `#include <inttypes.h>` to get all the `PRI`/`SCN` macros.