# Allocating memory for a structure within a function which returns pointer to struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a struct which represents a two dimensional mathematical matrix.

The function 'initMatrix' is intended to initialise a matrix of n rows by n columns, with the elements stored in a dynamically allocated array of doubles and set to zero.

However when I try to assign zero to the array by dereferencing the 'data' pointer within the struct [(according to this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581769/dereference-a-pointer-inside-a-structure-pointer), this causes the program to fail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int rows;
  int cols;
  double *data;
} Matrix;

Matrix *initMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
  Matrix *ptr;
  ptr = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 + sizeof(double) * rows * cols);
  if(ptr == NULL) printf("Couldn't allocate memory");
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      *(ptr->data) = 0; //error originating here
      ptr->data++;
    }
  }
  return ptr;
}

int main(void) 
{
  Matrix *mptr = initMatrix(2, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `data` is a pointer to some memory region, you will have to malloc this region separately, i.e.

```
ptr = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
ptr->data = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*rows*cols);
```

Pay attention, that you will also have to call `free` on `mptr->data` as well as on `mptr` in the end to return all heap-allocated memory.

That being said, you might want to simplify your program by returning a `Matrix` instead of `Matrix *` from `initMatrix`. Then, you will only have to care for allocating/freeing the `data` member:

```
Matrix initMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
  Matrix result;
  result.data = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * rows * cols);

  if(result.data == NULL) printf("Couldn't allocate memory");

  result.rows = rows;
  result.cols = cols;

  // initialization of result.data here, consider using memset() ...
  return result;
}
```

To initialize the memory to zero, you might want to use [memset](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) instead of a discrete loop.

Comment: You still have to zero the matrix (use `calloc`) and initialize the other members, but OP didn't do that last part (forgot) either.

Comment: BTW `if(result.data == NULL) printf("Couldn't allocate memory");`  is rather pointless, it will display the message if `malloc` fails but what happens then?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: added the member initialization

Answer (score 2):

```
ptr = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 + sizeof(double) * rows * cols);
```

you should do this for `ptr->data`, not for `ptr`.

Dereferencing `data` fails because you never allocated memory for it, so it's pointing nowhere (undefined behavior, to be precise).

So first allocate a `Matrix`, then allocate what's needed for `data`

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
ptr -> data = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 + sizeof(double) * rows * cols);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for the data separately and for the matrix separately. Also you should free the memory allocated inside the `initMatrix` function in your `main()`.

In addition to what all the other very good answers have mentioned about using `memset()` or `calloc()` instead of doing this yourself in 2 `for` loops, and so on, I want to mention a couple of things which the other posters have not answered, and also to capture the gist what I sense the OP was asking:

1. You are confusing a matrix which needs a `double **data` with a 1-d vector that contains the same number of elements and can be stored in `double *data`.

   That is why you are using the two `for` loops, I guess. You don't want 4 elements in a 1 row. You want 2 rows and 2 cols! You can look at the code below to see how that can be achieved.
2. Remember to free both the `mptr` and the `data`.
3. In addition in your code, you are not initializing `ptr->cols` and `ptr->rows`.

## Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double **data;
} Matrix;

Matrix *initMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    Matrix *ptr;
    ptr = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    ptr->cols = cols;
    ptr->rows = rows;
    ptr->data = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * rows);
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        ptr->data[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * cols);
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            ptr->data[i][j] = i*10+j;
            // printf("%d,%d,%lf", i, j, ptr->data[i][j]); // just for debugging
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    Matrix *mptr = initMatrix(2, 2);
    printf("rows:%d, cols:%d\n", mptr->rows, mptr->cols);

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            printf("element[%d][%d]:%lf\n",i,j,mptr->data[i][j]);
        }
    }

    free(mptr->data);
    free(mptr);

    return 0;
}
```

which produces the output:

> rows:2, cols:2 
> element[0][0]:0.000000
> element[0][1]:1.000000
> element[1][0]:10.000000
> element[1][1]:11.000000

which i just displayed to debug. You can change the line `ptr->data[i][j] = i*10+j;` and get whatever output you want, including all zeros.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I edited my answer and the code. I had found some other fallacies in it, that I have corrected. In addition, regarding `malloc()` failure, if `malloc()` fails, then to best of my knowledge and experience, it is time to pack up and go home `:)`. Puns aside, that depends on where this bit of code is running. If it is an embedded device, then we have serious problems to address. Yes `printf` would be useless in that case (except maybe to log, as the error message on malloc failure won't go in to the log by itself).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate the whole structure with one `malloc` you could use

```
typedef struct
{
  int rows;
  int cols;
  double data[1];
} Matrix;
```

In contrast to the other answers this allows to use a single `free`.

If your compiler supports arrays of size 0 you can also use `double data[0];`.

From C99 onward you can use an array without dimension in the structure:  `double data[];`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061038/10622916

Instead of calculating the size for `malloc` by adding the size of the structure fields' types you should better use `sizeof` or `offsetof` with the structure type `Matrix` because there may be some padding. (Probably not in your case but this depends on compiler implementation and your structure fields.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>  // for offsetof

typedef struct
{
  int rows;
  int cols;
  double data[1];
  // or with C99: double data[];
} Matrix;

Matrix *initMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
  Matrix *ptr;
  double *data;
  ptr = (Matrix *)malloc(
     offsetof(Matrix, data) // = size of Matrix without double data[1];
     // with C99's "double data[];" or with the non-standard 
     // "double data[0];" you can replace offsetof(...) with: sizeof(Matrix)
     + sizeof(double) * rows * cols); // dynamic array size
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed");
  } else {
    // save rows and columns for later accessing the matrix
    ptr->rows = rows;
    ptr->cols = cols;

    data = ptr->data;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        *(data) = 0;
        data++;
      }
    }
  }

  return ptr;
}

int main(void) 
{
  Matrix *mptr = initMatrix(2, 2);
  // use matrix

  // a single free is sufficient with the approach above
  free(mptr); mptr = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

Instead of incrementing the pointer `data` you can calculate the array index

```
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        ptr->data[i * cols + j] = 0;
      }
    }
```

Or for the 0-initialization you can use memset

```
    memset(ptr->data, 0, sizeof(double) * rows * cols);
```

Or use `calloc(1, offsetof(Matrix, data) + sizeof(double) * rows * cols);` instead of `malloc` to get zero initialized memory.

Comment: For the zero initialisation, use `calloc()` instead of `malloc`.